# How to write the string "^^^^" into a file

Tags: characters, shell-escape, write

I am trying to write `"^^^"` into an already opened file (under the variable `\myfile`) using the command

```
\immediate\write\myfile{"^^^"}
```

This, however results in an error.

I am however able to get `"^ ^ ^"` but unable to get those characters without the spacing.

Advance thanks for any suggestions/solutions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newwrite\myfile
\immediate\openout\myfile \jobname.txt
\immediate\write\myfile{"^^^"}
\immediate\write\myfile{"^^^^"}
\immediate\openout\myfile
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify a bit what you are after. What kind of file you wish to write to? What error do you get exactly? I think, posting an MWE would help.

Comment: I get no error. Please, make a full (but minimal) example.

Comment: Hi Jasper, egreg,   Compilation under pdflatex stops as follows: 
 \GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.74 \immediate\write\qizfile{^^^^}     ---  however, David Carlisle's answer below works.

Comment: @MuraliAgastya ah it gives no error in texlive 2022 pdflatex, but does in earlier releases

Answer (score 4):

In lualatex you need

```
\immediate\write20{\string^\string^\string^}
```

which also works in pdflatex, although the original version also works in that case in current latex (It would give an `inputenc` related error in pdflatex releases before 2022.)

Comment: note you have 4 ^^^^ in the title and 3 ^^^ in the question, the same answer works in either case, although the error message is different

Comment: Thank you David. That works, I am using pdflatex.

Comment: @MuraliAgastya you get no error in pdflatex so you do not need to do anything. I will add a MWE to your question (as you should have done)

Answer (score 2):

You needn't to prefix each `^` by `\string`. Another solution is to separate the `^` with something which expands to nothing:

```
\immediate\write20{^\empty^\empty^}
```